# How to unroll a cell array into a column vector?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a cell array, where each cell is a matrix of different size. I want to concatenate every elements of all the matrices into one column vector.
So

```matlab
X1=rand(2,3);  % Total 6 elements.
X2=rand(3,4);  % Total 12 elements.
X = {X1, X2};  % Total 18 elements in a 2-cell array.

% How to unroll everything from X into one giant column vector of size 18x1 ?

% Edit: The above example only shows two matrices, X1 and X2, but there could be n such matrices in the cell array.
X = {X1, X2, ... , Xn};
```

I can do this with a loop, but curious if there is a faster way. I looked into cell2mat and reshape, but can't get them to do this (dimension mismatch errors). Searches on web don't seem to help.

This is my solution with a for loop:

```matlab
unrolled_X=[];
for i=1:length(X)
  unrolled_X = [unrolled_X; X{i}(:)];
end
```

**Edit 2**: Thanks for the answers. I learned something new about perf. I benchmarked the 3 solutions by @HansHirse, @lucien-xhh, and @wolfie. A bit surprising results. Note I am actually running Octave (version 5.2.0.).

So the solution without cell2fun was fastest. Other 2 solutions both use cellfun, but was surprisingly close to the fastest, while the other was double of the fastest. Code and results follow.

**Code**

```matlab
function run_benchmarks()
  X={};
  for i=1:5
    X{i}=rand(1000,1000);
  end
  
  fprintf("unroll_with_cellfun: %f\n", benchmark(@()unroll_with_cellfun(X), 100));
  fprintf("unroll_with_cellfun2: %f\n", benchmark(@()unroll_with_cellfun2(X), 100));
  fprintf("unroll_with_vertcat: %f\n", benchmark(@()unroll_with_vertcat(X), 100));
  
end

function unrolled_X = unroll_with_cellfun(X)
  unrolled_X = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), X, 'UniformOutput', false).');
end

function unrolled_X = unroll_with_cellfun2(X)
  unrolled_X = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:).', X, 'UniformOutput', false)).';
end

function unrolled_X = unroll_with_vertcat(X)
  unrolled_X = cell(length(X),1);
  for ii = 1:length(X)
    unrolled_X{ii} = X{ii}(:);
  end
  unrolled_X = vertcat( unrolled_X{:} );
end


function elapsed_time_in_seconds = benchmark(f, N)
  % benchmark runs the function 'f' N times and returns the elapsed time in seconds.

  timeid = tic;
  for i=1:N
    output = f();
  end
  elapsed_time_in_seconds = toc(timeid);
end
```

**Results:**

```
octave:161> run_benchmarks
unroll_with_cellfun: 1.240324
unroll_with_cellfun2: 0.606957   <-- Close to fastest.
unroll_with_vertcat: 0.597657    <-- FASTEST
```

Surprised to see cellfun2 is almost same as the fastest solution, and that cellfun takes 2x time even it's almost same as cellfun2.

Comment: I suspect that the two cellfun answers might be giving different results, one interleaving the values. This would be the cause of the slowdown. Did you double-check the results? The solution interleaving the values wouldn’t work if the cell array had different-sized arrays in it.

Comment: Note that you X in the tests is a column array, whereas in Hans’ and Lucien’s answers it is a row array.

Comment: Also, did you “warm up” before doing the test? The first call to a function tends to be a lot slower than subsequent ones.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The code for benchmark function is at end in my question. It calls the function N times and then returns the total time. Should a warm-up be done before the loop in the benchmark function? If yes, any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Just run the benchmark function twice in a row, and take the times for the second run.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Did that. Got similar results. Thanks for the tip. I will create another questions to seek improvements to my benchmark function.

Comment: I just ran your benchmark in MATLAB R2017a, "cellfun2" is almost 2x slower than "cellfun", and "vertcat" is more than 2x faster. In MATLAB the looping is optimized, and so the call to `cellfun` has a significant overhead. I guess the added `.'` operation adds to the time? -- But I don't see why "cellfun" would be slower than "cellfun2" in Octave. It makes no sense.

Comment: OK, I broke out Octave (v.5.2.0 on Linux), and ran your benchmark there. I see "cellfun" taking 2.28 s, "cellfun2" taking 2.07, and "vertcat" 2.04. "cellfun" is indeed slower, maybe caused by the transpose on the cell array? But it's not 2x, more like 1.1x. Also, you must have a really fast computer...

Comment: Good to see more reports! I am running Octave 5.2.0 on Windows 10. CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 3600 which a 6 core (12 threads with hyperthreading) base speed at 3.6GHz. But Octave doesn't make use of multiple threads I think. I only see one core getting spiked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preallocating your loop will be more performant and better practise

```
unrolled_X = cell(length(X),1);
for ii = 1:length(X)
  unrolled_X{ii} = X{ii}(:);
end
unrolled_X = vertcat( unrolled_X{:} );
```

Any shorthand like `cellfun` is basically this loop in disguise, and `cell2mat` uses a loop for concatenation under the hood but has additional checks so may actually cause a minor slow-down.

Comment: Thanks for the better practices; and the top about potential slowdown with cell2mat. I will report back after a running benchmark of this and @HansHirse's answer.

Comment: I added benchmarking results as an edit to the question. cellfun+cell2mat way is indeed slower. But the biggest slowness is perhaps due to the need to transpose, rather than cell2fun + cellmat per se.

Comment: The transpose should be very computationally light, I expect it's just the extra stuff wrapped up within `cellfun` and `cell2mat` to make them robust

Comment: You can gain a bit (<10% on MATLAB R2017a) by skipping the call to `vertcat`: `unrolled_X{ii} = X{ii}(:).'`, and then `unrolled_X = [unrolled_X{:}].'`.

Comment: @Cris good find, I'm slightly surprised that appending row vectors is quicker than appending columns, I guess there's probably some additional checks... Perhaps `cat(1,__)` would see the same speedup

Comment: `vertcat` does a lot of checking. And it’s a function call. The `[...]` syntax gets optimized by the JIT, there’s no function to call. `cat` is a function call too. Although I don’t know if builtins are more efficient than M-file functions.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to flatten all matrices using an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Then, feed the modified cell array **as "column vector"** to [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html), i.e. transposing the modified cell arry beforehand.

Here's an example, in which all that becomes a one-liner (tested with MATLAB Online):

```matlab
X1 = rand(2, 3);
X2 = rand(3, 4);
X3 = rand(1, 5);
X = {X1, X2, X3}

unrolled_X = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), X, 'UniformOutput', false).')
```

Some examplary output (generated with Octave 6.1.0):

```
X =
{
  [1,1] =
     0.2781   0.3303   0.7424
     0.3314   0.4878   0.6254

  [1,2] =
     0.567344   0.848374   0.035421   0.171656
     0.359233   0.482265   0.327617   0.188834
     0.088272   0.771683   0.763845   0.181979

  [1,3] =
     0.9843   0.7817   0.9399   0.5453   0.3310
}

unrolled_X =

   0.278085
   0.331438
   0.330314
   0.487774
   0.742395
   0.625360
   0.567344
   0.359233
   0.088272
   0.848374
   0.482265
   0.771683
   0.035421
   0.327617
   0.763845
   0.171656
   0.188834
   0.181979
   0.984326
   0.781678
   0.939857
   0.545296
   0.331043
```

In fact, using `cellfun` with an anonymous function is something like a loop in disguise, but it should be still more efficient than your loop, since you're appending to an array.

Answer (score 3):

One Solution: Try `X = {[X1(:); X2(:)]}` , then use `cell2mat`

Two Solution:

```
clear
X1 = rand(2,3);  
X2 = rand(3,4);
X3 = rand(4,5);
X = {X1, X2, X3};
XX = cellfun(@(x) x(:)', X, 'UniformOutput', false);
cell2mat(XX)
```

Comment: There could be more than 2 matrices. I showed two just to present the example. I updated the question to indicate there could n such matrixes in the cell array.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty to benchmark these, and updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Octave you can use [`cellindexmat`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cellindexmat.html):

```
unrolled_X = vertcat(cellindexmat(X, ':'){:});
```

Comment: This is the fastest on Octave 5.2.0!